# How to add multiple values to dict key?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
    def chunk(it, size):
        it = iter(it)
        return iter(lambda: tuple(islice(it, size)), ()) 

    Results = []
    values = list(df['values'])
    name = list(df['name'])

    mergedata = {name_: counts_ for name_, counts_ in zip(name, list(chunk(values, 20)))}
    print(mergedata)

    for name_, counts in mergedata.items():
        if all( 5 < values_ < 16 for values_ in counts ):
            Results.append(f'{name_} passed.\n')
        else:
            Results.append(f'{name_} failed.\n')
```

I have a script that reads two columns from a csv file. 'Name' and Value'. 
Then based on the values it gives a pass or fail if all values for that individual is [5,16]. But the chunk command only give me the last value. Ex: 'Nick: 5' and 'Dan: 4'. Each person has 20 values assigned to them. What am I missing in my code?

chunk(values, 20) # Chunks and prints 20 random values for first individual(Nick) Ex: Nick: 9,3,5,2,6,7,.....
chunk(values, 1) # Chunk and prints last value for all individuals:  Ex: 'Nick: 5' and 'Dan: 4'.

.`Name Values
Nick 4
Nick 14
Nick 6
Nick 4
Nick 11
Nick 17
Nick 19
... ...
James 12
James 4
James 1
James 2
James 5
... ...`

Goal: {Nick: 4,14,6,4,11,17,19...}
James: {James: 12,4,1,2,5,...}

Output: Nick failed (Because of 17 and 19)
James passed

Comment: Fundamentally no, a key is mapped to one value. However, that value can be a *container*, like a `list` or *another `dict`*, which itself can have multiple values

Comment: It looks like your values are all integers.  If so, `5 < values_ < 6` cannot possibly be true; one or both of those comparisons should be `<=`.

Comment: Mistype. the range is [5,16]

Comment: Can you give a cleaner example of a sample input and expected output?  Keep it simple.

Comment: See the updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're processing columns into a dict of names with accumulated values, consider a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

**Given**

```
import itertools as it
import collections as ct


pred = lambda x : 5 < x < 16

# Sample data (bad + good)
values = list(range(-10, -5)) + list(range(6, 11))
names = ["Nick"] * 5 + ["James"] * 5
```

**Code**

```
def make_dict(names, values):
    """Return a defaultdict of names and listed values."""
    data = ct.defaultdict(list)
    for name, value in zip(names, values):
        data[name].append(value)
    return data


def process_dict(data, pred):
    """Return a list of strings; pass if values satisfy the predicate."""
    result = []
    for name, counts in data.items():
        if all(pred(v) for v in counts):
            result.append(f"{name} passed.\n")
        else:
            result.append(f"{name} failed.\n")
    return result
```

**Demo**

```
d = make_dict(names, values)
d
# defaultdict(list, {'Nick': [-10, -9, -8, -7, -6], 'James': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})

process_dict(d, pred)
# ['Nick failed.\n', 'James passed.\n']
```

---

**Details**

- we use a sample data of names and values
- `make_dict()` returns a dictionary of name-values pairs.  `defaultdict` makes an empty list if a key is missing, so we can safely append values without a `KeyError`; this obviates chunking.
- `process_dict()` validates passing data using a predicate.  A predicate is a function that returns `True` or `False` based on a condition, e.g. `5 < x < 16`.